# How to install pyzmq for iPython Notebook in a Python 3 virtual environment?

Tags: python, python3, virtualenv, ipython

I wanted to use iPython Notebook in Python 3 on Ubuntu 14.04. Because I have both Python 2.7 and Python 3.4 installed on my system--and for other implementation-specific reasons--I decided to use a Python virtual environment (with `virtualenv`). Very little has been written about this topic so far...

- [How to install Python package pyzmq properly?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100529/how-to-install-python-package-pyzmq-properly/100540#100540)
- [How to install the latest IPython notebook in Ubuntu 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/390457/how-to-install-the-latest-ipython-notebook-in-ubuntu-12-04)

These reports don't specifically handle Python 3 and virtual environments. Furthermore, the the [official](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/install/install.html) and various [unofficial guides](http://opentechschool.github.io/python-data-intro/core/notebook.html) to installing iPython Notebook don't deal with this use case, either.

**The main problem I encountered is with the ZMQ library.** To install the library and the Python bindings system-wide I used `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get install libzmq3 libzmq3-dev python3-zmq
```

But when I tried `pip install ipython[notebook]`, either inside or outside my `virtualenv`, the installation would fail with exit status 1 and the warnings:

```
Warning: Detected ZMQ version: 4.0.4, but pyzmq targets ZMQ 4.0.5.
Warning: libzmq features and fixes introduced after 4.0.4 will be unavailable.
```

**I confirmed in Synaptic Package Manager that the `libzmq3` package for Ubuntu is only version 4.0.4.** As an alternative, [I tried this fix](https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/wiki/Building-and-Installing-PyZMQ#pip), having `pyzmq` build its own `libzmq` dependency:

```
 pip install pyzmq --install-option="--zmq=bundled"
```

**But this failed because it couldn't find a certain header file:**

```
    buildutils/initlibsodium.c:10:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include "Python.h"
                    ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

**Next, I built `libzmq` version 4.0.5 from source.**

```
wget http://download.zeromq.org/zeromq-4.0.5.tar.gz
tar -xzvf zeromq-4.0.5.tar.gz && rm zeromq-4.0.5.tar.gz
cd /usr/local/zmq/zeromq-4.0.5
./configure
make -j 6
sudo make install
```

No problems encountered. After this, I tried to install `pyzmq` in my virtual environment with:

```
easy_install pyzmq
```

I also tried building `pyzmq` from source. In both cases, I could see from the output that the proper ZMQ version (4.0.5) was detected, but the installation failed because I didn't have Cython installed (a not-well-documented dependency for building `pyzmq`, in my opinion).

**After installing Cython for Python 3...**

```
sudo apt-get install cython3
```

I tried installing `pyzmq` again with `pip` and with `easy_install` both inside and outside the virtual environment; it still didn't work. **This message was delivered despite `cython3` being installed:**

```
Fatal: Cython-generated file 'zmq/backend/cython/_device.c' not found.
            Cython >= 0.16 is required to compile pyzmq from a development branch.
            Please install Cython or download a release package of pyzmq.
```

And this file structure:

```
$ ls -l zmq/backend/cython/
checkrc.pxd         context.pxd         __init__.py         _poll.pyx           utils.pxd           
constant_enums.pxi  context.pyx         libzmq.pxd          rebuffer.pyx        utils.pyx           
constants.pxi       _device.pyx         message.pxd         socket.pxd          _version.pyx        
constants.pyx       error.pyx           message.pyx         socket.pyx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I considered installing iPython Notebook system-wide (outside a virtual environment). I had previously tried just install `pyzmq` system-wide but this wasn't enough.

**When I considered install iPython Notebook outside the virtual environment, I realized, "How do I get `pip` to discriminate between Python 2.7 and Python 3.4?"** I went searching and [found this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12262143/2343309). In fact, it turns out my central problem was related to `pip`. I installed the `pip` corresponding to my Python 3 version:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
sudo easy_install3 pip
```

And after that, installing both `pyzmq` and `ipython[notebook]` worked perfectly inside my virtual environment:

```
pip3.4 install pyzmq
pip install ipython[notebook]
```

I accidently used `pip` instead of `pip3.4` for `ipython[notebook]` but it works anyway:

```
(my-virtual-env)me@computer:~$ pip freeze
Jinja2==2.7.3
MarkupSafe==0.23
certifi==14.05.14
ipython==2.3.1
pyzmq==14.4.1
tornado==4.0.2
```

**However, using `pip3.4` was necessary to get `pyzmq` installed in a Python 3 virtual environment.**

Comment: And to get iPython Notebook running, instead of `ipython notebook` use `ipython3 notebook`.

Answer (score 6):

The "Python.h" error message indicates that you are missing the `python3-dev`package, which you need to build any Python extensions (Python modules written in C), which you can get with:

```
apt-get install python3-dev
```

To get up and running from scratch:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install python3-dev python3-pip build-essential libzmq3-dev
pip3 install virtualenv
virtualenv -p $(which python3) myenv
source myenv/bin/activate
pip install pyzmq
python -c 'import zmq; print(zmq.zmq_version())'
# 4.0.4
```

The installed packages:

- build-essential: compilers and headers for building things on Ubuntu.
- python3-dev: headers (Python.h) needed for compiling any Python extensions.
- libzmq3-dev: the libzmq library and its headers. This is optional, but recommended. PyZMQ will link against libzmq found on the system if it can, otherwise it will build libzmq itself as a Python extension.
- pip, virtualenv: Shouldn't be needed, but used to workaround [Ubuntu's bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python3.4/+bug/1290847) that breaks `python3 -m venv`.

I ran the above commands in a base `ubuntu:14.04` docker container to verify that they are sufficient to successfully build pyzmq in a virtualenv.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I'm aware of the `-dev` family of packages so I'm pretty sure I would have had it installed at the time (I just checked and I currently do). At any rate, my particular problem seemed to hinge, at the time, on using the correct implementation of `pip` (`pip` for Python 3).

Comment: Missing `Python.h` means you didn't have the Python headers at compile time. It's possible you had `python-dev` but not `python3-dev` when you ran it. I would be interested to hear if you still have this problem running the install after knowing you have python3-dev.

Comment: If you are in a virtualenv `pip` always corresponds to the version in the env. You never need to use `pipX` in a virtualenv, and further probably *shouldn't* because it's the easiest way to get out of your env by accident (e.g. pip3.4 in a Python 3.3 env will work, but will install outside the env, whereas `pip` will *always* install in the active env). `pipX` should only be used when you are *not* using envs.